# String dateTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

How do I fix an error? When I send a message, the date appears correctly, but when I receive a message, the date appears incorrectly. For example, 5 p.m., the date appears at 8 p.m. Here is a three-hour difference.

AdapterChat:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));
String dateTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();
```

ChatActivity:

```
String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I tried changing Locale.US to Locale.getDefault, but the error was not fixed.

AdapterChat:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));
String dateTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();
```

ChatActivity:

```
String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Have you tried `cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));` ?

Comment: You're using buggy old datetime classes that have long been superseded. You should be recording `Instant`s of sending/receipt that are absolute and universal and then presenting that to the user in the form of most use to them. e.g. `Instant sendingNow = Instant.now();DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");String userFriendlyNow = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dtf);` (Obviously, hanging on to `sendingNow`)

Comment: What timezone is the Calendar using on each end?  What timezone is the DateFormat using on each end?  If you use the java.time package, you won’t have to wonder.  Of course, you could just send the timestamp as a `long` in your message, since that will be timezone-agnostic, and let the receiver of the message format it as they wish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’m sorry, I cannot compile your code, which probably would have made answering your question easier. We’d love to have a [mre], please?

Answer (score 2):

### Missing zone/offset

Your transmitted text lacks a vital part: **Time zone or offset-from-UTC**. You send/receive only a date & time-of-day. A date with time is inherently ambiguous. Does noon on January 23rd mean noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three different moments, several hours apart?

To determine a moment, a point on the timeline, you must provide all three elements:

- date
- time-of-day
- time zone or offset

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the terribly flawed date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### ISO 8601

Do not exchange date-time values in localized formats. Use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

### `java.time.Instant`

Capture the current moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds by using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8691 format.

```
String output = instant.now() ;
```

> 2024-03-15T15:33:45.067355Z

The `Z` on the end is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, meaning an offset of zero. Pronounced “Zulu”.

The receiver can reconstitute an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

### `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

Adjust from UTC to a time zone to produce a [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

### Localized text

Generate text for presentation in localized format using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

---

To learn more, search Stack Overflow. These topics have been addressed many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Calendar.  Use classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

As was stated, the sender/recipients can format a time stamp themselves in what ever form that meets their requirements.  The following adjusts the time zone between East and West for a given Instant in time using your specified format.

```
Instant time = Instant.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(time, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));

System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));

ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(time, ZoneId.of("US/Pacific"));
System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
```

prints

```
09/03/2024 02:24 PM
09/03/2024 11:24 AM
```